# Get all the series related to particular category in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, bar-chart

I am using highchart to draw the horizontal bar graph. I am using two series in the bar graph. One series is used for background filler. Other series contains data. If i click anywhere in the bar, I want to get the other series bar data. Suppose if i click background filler series also i want to get other series bar data. For this i tried the following code but i will get the data only if click on that particular series. If i click on the background filler series i dont get the data.

Following code I tried in the highchart point click event

```
point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function (e) {
                                if (e.point.series.options.clickable) {
                                    console.log(this.y);
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Please help me to get all the series list in click event, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the complete highcharts configuration you are using, along with at least a part of your series configuration please. That would make this question a lot easier to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all series in point click event use:

```
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function() {
                    console.log(this.series.chart.series);
                }
            }
        }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/92a8wq7u/

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how do i get the values from that array.

Comment: Hi user2703151, you asked how get all the series list in click event. Please take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/aq6kn72b/ to check how to get point value from specific series.

Comment: Thank you a lot. It's Very helpful.